# How many different committees can be formed when certain people refuse to serve together?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From a group of 8 women and 6 men, a committee consisting of 3 men and 3 women is to be formed. How many different committees are possible for each of the following cases

(a) 2 of the men refuse to serve together

(b) 2 of the women refuse to serve together

(c) 1 man and 1 women refuse to serve together

---

I tried this much, I don't know how and why should I include the people who refuse?

(a) $\binom{8}{3}\binom{4}{3}$

(b) $\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$

(c)$\binom{7}{3}\binom{5}{3}$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, are these separate scenarios? Or are these constraints for the same question?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer (a) and leave the rest for you to solve on your own.

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the two men that refuse to serve together

There are three types of committees

1. Neither $M_1$ nor $M_2$ are on it.
2. Only $M_1$ is
3. Only $M_2$ is

---

For (1), you need to choose 3 from 4 men. The number of ways to do this is $\binom{4}{3} = 4$

For (2), 2 more men have to chosen from 4 now. The number of ways is $\binom{4}{2} = 6$

For (3), the answer is the same as (2).

The total number of ways to choose the men is 16. For each of these, there are $\binom{8}{3} = 56$ ways to choose the women.

---

Therefore, the total ways to choose the committee should be $(16)(56) = 896$

Comment: Actually I had not seen the word work together , so I was stuck

Comment: In case 2 and 3, 2 men have to be chosen from 4, not 5. Another way to see it, there are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to chose the men and $\binom{4}{1}=4$ ways are forbidden, so there are 16 ways to choose the men.

Comment: @Gribouillis You're right. Thanks for catching that. Fixed.

Comment: @Gribouillis How do I know 4 ways are forbidden ?

Comment: Because that is the number of ways to choose both men in the committee

Comment: Because you must remove the groups containing the two men that don't want to be together. There are only 4 ways to choose the third man, so there are only 4 such groups.

Comment: I understood there are 4 ways to choose the third man, but how is it that there are 4 ways that two men won't work together :(

Comment: @JohnWhite can u please explain how are there 4 ways to choose both men in committee?

Comment: Once the two men are fixed, there is still one man left to choose from the remaining 4 men which can be done in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways

Comment: @JohnWhite okay, got it :)